# Why is publishing final fields safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, final

I am currently reading [*Java Concurrency in Practice* by Brian Goetz](http://jcip.net/). On page 51. In one of the footnotes, he stated:

> While it may seem that field values set in a constructor are the first
>   values written to those fields and therefore that there are no “older”
>   values to see as stale values, the Object constructor first writes the
>   default values to all fields before subclass constructors run. It is
>   therefore possible to see the default value for a field as a stale
>   value.

So, the concept of final fields is not clear to me now. Consider the sample class:

```
public class MyClass{
    private final MyImmutableClass mic;

    public MyClass(){
        mic = MyImmutableClass.empty();
    }
}
```

According to the above footnote, the `mic` field is ***assigned twice***, once by the `Object`'s constructor and once by the `MyClass`'s constructor itself. Now, imagine that we published a `MyClass` object unsafely (e.g. through a `public` field):

```
public final MyClass mc;
```

Who guarantees that `mc` is always observed by any thread in a consistent state? Why can't some thread accidentally observe the default value?

To my knowledge, the `final` field itself only guarantees that the reference cannot be assigned after object construction. If we declared `mc` volatile, that would be clear. Any thread reading the field should read it from the memory directly. It's prohibited to read it from cache.

UPD: The publication example:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    class MyRunnable implements Runnable(){
        private SomeClass sc;
        public MyRunnable(SomeClass sc){
            this.sc = sc;
        }
        public void run(){
            //do some with sc
        }
    }
    SomeClass sc = getInitialized();
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    MyRunnable mr = new MyRunnable(sc);
    //submiting mr to es 10 times
    es.awaitTemination();
    es.shutdown();
}

private static SomeClass getInitialized(){
    SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
    sc. initialize();
    return sc;
}
public class SomeClass
    public MyClass mc;

    public void initialize(){
        mc = new MyClass();
    }
}
```

A `SomeClass` instance is going to be published across multiple threads. Can some thread observe the default value of the `mic` field?

Comment: Technically, **Brian Goetz is incorrect** when he says "Object constructor first writes the default values to all fields". [JLS section 12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) describes how new instances are created and "all the instance variables in the new object, including those declared in superclasses, are initialized to their default values (§4.12.5)" happens *before* any of the constructors, including the constructor of superclass `java.lang.Object`, is invoked.

Comment: Then again, it doesn't make a difference since the very next thing to be invoked after the default values have been written is the `java.lang.Object` constructor

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Great comment, very interesting. Thanks much!!

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt But I don't see where the `happens-before` relationship specified.

Comment: It's not a happens-before relationship is in the Java Memory Model. It's just happening before, see this sentence in section 12.5: "Just before a reference to the newly created object is returned as the result, the indicated constructor is processed to initialize the new object using the following procedure:"

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Not clear what it means. What is the `reference to the newly created object`. Is it an object with default values?

Comment: I should qualify that. Although 12.5 doesn't imply a happens-before relationship, there is one in any case due to 17.4.4: "The write of the default value (zero, false, or null) to each variable synchronizes-with the first action in every thread." And since a constructor is invoked on a thread, and x synchronized-with y implies x happens-before y, this also means there is a happens-before relation between the assigment of default variables and the invocation of the java.lang.Object superclass constructor.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt what if I provide an initial value in the field's declaration? I believe no default value will be written to it, right?

Comment: I spent some time reading the java spec, and now I believe it will also be initialized to default value at first, and then the initializer is executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mc` in your example is an instance variable. This means you must have a fully initialized instance of the class that contains `mc` in order for any code that accesses `mc` of some instance not to throw a `NullPointerException`. Therefore `mc` will definitely be initialized by the time it is accessed.

Comment: So, if we have not accessed a variable before, there is no thread-local cache, so we have to read it from memory directly. Correct?

Comment: @St.Antario I'm not sure I understand your comment. Which code would be accessing `mc` in your example? Can you show some code snippet I can comment on?

Comment: I added the example of publication.

Comment: @St.Antario You didn't show where you call `initialize` in the new snippet

Answer (score 1):

> ...the Object constructor first writes the default values to all
>   fields before subclass constructors run...

`Object` class constructor cannot see `MyClass` members which only belong to `MyClass` (not inherited from `Object`). Therefore the above statement is correct and `Object` class cannot instantiate the member variable `mic`.

> ...According to the above footnote, the mic field is assigned twice,
>   once by the Object's constructor and once by the MyClass's constructor
>   itself...

No. `Object` constructor only initializes it's member variables. After then `MyClass` constructor will initialize it's `mic`. Finally you will have the `MyClass` instance. Hence `mic` is not getting assigned twice even `mic` is non-final.

Publication example: Code snippet is not completed. However access something across multiple threads depends on many things such as *whether it is a static member?*, *parent is getting referenced as a static member somewhere?*, *where and when the `mc` is getting initialized?* (default value `null` definitely via constructor). *If not a static member, it should be a singleton*, etc...

Comment: I really didn't understand what you meant. He says that the `Object`'s constructor writes default values to all fields....

Comment: What "he" said is correct. You are getting confused with the super() constructor calling...

Comment: Ah, you meant that just calling super() leaves all fields of a derived class  with their default values, right?